# Is wcslen part of the ISO/IEC 14882:2003 C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, 64-bit, strlen

While porting a C++ Program from 32 to 64 bit under windows I realized _tcslen is not supported and instead strlen/wcslen (for non-unicode/unicode) should be used. I started to wonder

1. If wcslen is part of the ISO/IEC 14882:2003 C++ standard library. I see this function is supported both by g++ as well as VC++. Also in [open group](http://pubs.opengroup.org) I found a reference stating `The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard` but didn't mention if its C89 or c99.
2. Is it documented somewhere that _tcslen is not compatible with Win64? Even the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't hint a thing.
3. For Unicode can wcslen be used inadvertently instead of _tcslen?

Comment: `_tcslen` is just a #define for either `wcslen` or `strlen` depending on whether `_UNICODE` is defined. You can always copy tchar.h or make your own version to make this work on any platform. If it's not working, you probably just need to include tchar.h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes it is. Table 48 in section 21.4 gives `wcslen` as one of the functions declared in `<cwchar>`.
2. `_tcslen` is also available when doing x64 builds.
3. As long as `_UNICODE` is defined then `_tcslen` expands to `wcslen`. The only thing you gain by using `_tcslen` is that *theoretically* you can make an ANSI build of your application by flipping a switch; *practically* there is nothing you stand to gain from this (ANSI builds in 2012 are simply atrocious IMHO) and it takes actual work to make your build work both ways. I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my first question. Looking forward for the rest part of my question.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I am aware of how _tcslen expands differently for ANSI/UNICODE. The piece of code I was looking at is guaranteed to be executed only for UNICODE, so I was looking forward to safely substitute _tcslen with wcslen.

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered your first question already (the answer to it is "yes."), so I'll answer the other two questions:

2) _tcslen is perfectly compatible with Win64.

3) It would be wrong to use `wcslen` instead of `_tcslen` if you deal with some string of `TCHAR` values (e.g. `LPTSTR` or `LPCTSTR`) but you don't have `_UNICODE` defined. If `_UNICODE` is not defined, `TCHAR` expands to `char` so `LPTSTR` is `char*` - which cannot be passed to `wcslen`. So the compiler barfs.

See the remarks section on the [MSDN page for strlen/wcslen/...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for some discussion about what _tcslen expands to.

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E), Ch. 21, Table 48, p. 412.  The `wcslen()` is indeed part of the standard, presented by `#include <cwchar>`.

The standard does not mention `tcslen()` or `_tcslen()`.  These seem to be Microsoft extensions.  If they are not compatible with your target platform and are not mentioned in the standard, it might be preferable to stick with `wcslen()`.

For information:  Symbols that start with an underscore usually represent implementation details.  By prefacing `tcslen` with an underscore, your toolchain's developers are probably warning you that `_tcslen()` might disappear in a future version.  And it appears that this is exactly what happened to you.

I too occasionally use underscored features, when I don't have a good alternative; but then I must update my code whenever I change toolchains.  So, usually, the standard is best.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my first question. Looking forward for the rest part of my question.